# Using patern attribute in html

Tags: html, forms, design-patterns

I want to use the pattern attribute to allow only UPPERCASE LETTERS, NUMBERS AND FORWARD SLASH. (A-Z, 0-9,/).
How do do I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

use `regex`:

```
([A-Z][A-Z0-9][- /.])\w+
```

it allows `upper case` ,`numbers`,and `/`. thanks.